# TabLayout custom menu

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a TabLayout containing tabs as intents to activities.
I want to set custom menu items for each tab, but the onCreateOptionsMenu version called is the Host's version.
How can I make the menu items created by each activity on its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A call to

```
boolean result = super.onCreateOptionsMenu();
// do anything but don't change anything in the menu in case of the specific menu u want
return result;
```

Do the same with onPrepareOptionsMeny()

Answer (score 4):

If all you want is the sub-Activity's menu instead of the TabActivity's menu, then you just need it to stop propagation of onCreateOptionsMenu().  That is, normally you call "`return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);`" at the end, but if you just `return true` instead then only that sub-Activity's menu should be displayed for any particular tab.

Answer (score 0):

```
int cur = tabHost.getCurrentTab();      
                Log.i("current tab for asdasff", ""+cur);
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(cur).setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new OnCreateContextMenuListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
                        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
                        //createMenu(menu);
                    }
                }
```